# Silverlight Border FAIL !

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-4.0

Border FAIL !!
I have a border in XAML code that is defined right after that main canvas:

```
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"
...      VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Border x:Name="JohnnyBorder" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#FF677B8B" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
```

And in the code I position the border ike this:

```
JohnnyBorder = (Border)appCanvas.FindName("JohnnyBorder");
                JohnnyBorder.Height = App.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
                JohnnyBorder.Width = App.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
```

But it does not work.  JohnnyBoarder's bottom line is a few percentages above the bottom of the browser.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be a lot more natural to have your `Border` *around* you `Canvas`:

```
<Border>
    <Canvas>
        ...
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```

By default the `Border` will fill the page and the `Canvas` will fill the `Border`.

Answer (score 0):

The page hosting your silverlight app may not be giving the Silverlight app 100% height.  Check either the html or aspx file hosting your silverlight app and ensure it's set to 100% height.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
```